# Consultar tabela por período

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-server-2014

Tenho duas tabelas, "Contato" e "PedVenda", como posso fazer uma consulta que gere durante um período, por exemplo, de 01/01/2019 a 30/01/2019 a quantidade de vendas entre 10:00h e 16:00h em cada dia 01/01, 02/01, 03/01 e assim por diante até 30/01? 
A tabela "Contato" mencionei porque preciso pegar o nome do cliente que fica nela.

Dessa forma eu consigo pegar do período inteiro e também consigo se executar a consulta considerando apenas o dia, mas queria saber se consigo resolver tudo em apenas uma query de 01/01/2019 até 30/01/2019 pegando todos os dias.

```sql
SELECT P.PvCod, C.ContNome, P.EmpCod, P.PvDatHor, P.PvStatus, P.PvValTot
FROM PedVend P, Contato C 
WHERE P.ContCod = C.ContCod
and P.EmpCod = 55 
and P.PvDatHor BETWEEN '26/12/2018 10:00:00' and '26/12/2018 16:00:01'
```

Comment: Coloque o período desejado no BETWEEN, acrescente uma cláusula GROUP BY por dia e utilize a função de agregação COUNT.

Comment: Então, pra ver se entendi certo, eu teria que adicionar a cláusula GROUP BY no final do WHERE e no SELECT utilizar a função COUNT ? Se for dessa forma da um erro dizendo que os outros campos do SELECT são inválidos na lista de seleção porque não utilizam função de agregação.

Comment: Sua dúvida seria na cláusula where?

Comment: Isso, junto com a função GROUP BY

Comment: WHERE (P.PvDatHor BETWEEN @DATAINICIO AND GETDATE()) AND (DATEPART(HOUR, P.PvDatHor) BETWEEN 10 AND 16) Tente isso na data do seu Where. E creio que não há necessidade de utilizar o group by, dependendo da sua necessidade

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um teste na estrutura que tenho aqui, e assim deu certo, caso queira exatamente a quantidade e não a quantidade de registro, você deve substituir as colunas por um count() e incluir um group by no final da query.

```
DECLARE @DATAINICIO DATETIME;
DECLARE @DATAFINAL DATETIME;
    SET @DATAINICIO = --DATAINICIO    
    SET @DATAFINAL = --DATAFINAL
SELECT P.PvCod, C.ContNome, P.EmpCod, P.PvDatHor, P.PvStatus, P.PvValTot FROM PedVend P, Contato C 
        WHERE P.ContCod = C.ContCod and P.EmpCod = 55 and (P.PvDatHor BETWEEN @DATAINICIO AND @DATAFINAL) AND (DATEPART(HOUR, P.PvDatHor) BETWEEN 10 AND 16)
```

Comment: Neste caso, não pega a quantidade diária certo? 01/01, 02/01, 03/01 e assim por diante até 30/01. Desculpe, só estou tentando entender melhor o código.

Comment: Pra trazer a quantidade você deverá agrupar os dados, acrescente um group by no final da query e um Count(P.PvCod) para as colunas.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Espero ter ajudado! :)

Answer (score 0):

A query abaixo retorna a quantidade de registros na `PedVend` (usando o filtro `EmpCod = 5` e de horário entre as 10:00 e 16:00), agrupados por data.

```sql
SELECT P.PvDatHor, count(*)
FROM PedVend P
WHERE P.EmpCod = 55 
and cast(P.PvDatHor as time) BETWEEN '10:00:00' and '16:00:01'
GROUP BY CAST(P.PvDatHor AS DATE)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Isso ajudou a resolver o problema?

Comment: Sim, fiz apenas algumas alterações mas ajudou muito a ter noção de como implementar aqui.